# Function for extracting counter-factual ARIMA forecasts in R

Tags: r, forecasting

I have built an ARIMA(9,0,2) model with nonzero mean. I would like to use this model to create  counter-factual forecasts. That is, conditional on only having the first nine observations, I'm looking for an R function that can produce a forecast for the **tenth**, eleventh, and so on observations using the ARIMA(9,0,2) model that I estimated by using all of the data.

R functions `forecast` and `predict` do not, to my knowledge, accomplish the counterfactual portion of this. Function `forecast` picks up where your time series *ends* and makes predictions using the fitted model, but I have not found a way to trick it into giving me forecasts using observations 1-9 to predict observation 10 onward, or using observations 2-10 for predicting observation 11 on onward. Likewise, `predict` creates the next several observations picking up where the data stops. I haven't found a workaround for either of these functions.

R function `fitted` just creates a 1-step forecast, not a **long-run forecast** for each time point in the available data.

I've pasted code for creating some fake time-series data, an Arima object and a demonstration of how `forecast` does not provide a helpful output for my question.

```
setseed(2314)
fake.data   <- rnorm(10,sd=5)
for(i in 1:200){
    model.length    <- 9
    lower       <- length(fake.data)-9+1
    upper       <- length(fake.data)
    new.obs <- rnorm(1,mean=0,sd=0.25)+fake.data[lower:upper]%*%c(  -0.1, 0.1, -0.15,0.15,-0.2,0.2,-0.5,0.3,0.9)
    fake.data   <- c(fake.data, new.obs)
}
plot(fake.data)
fitted.arima    <- auto.arima(fake.data, ic="bic")
plot(forecast(fitted.arima))
```

Clearly the output of `forecast` is not a prediction at points in time which were observed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the parameters using the `fixed` argument. Below an example:

```
m<-arima(LakeHuron,order=c(9,0,2))
coe<-m$coef
mn<-arima(LakeHuron[1:9],order=c(9,0,2),fixed=coe)

sum(coe==mn$coef)
12 # all coefficients are equal

predict(mn,n.ahead =10)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `forecast` package by Hyndman et. al. has a nice wrapper around ARIMA that allows you to do the previous work with the same result, but a slightly friendlier API (imho).

```
library(forecast)
m <- Arima(LakeHuron, order=c(9,0,2))
mn <- Arima(LakeHuron, model=m)
predict(mn, n.ahead=10)
```

Supplying the `model=` argument with an argument of a previously generated model does the work of the above.

Comment: I now know this because I searched for the same solution, and this post came up with the answer I needed as I was typing out my question.  However, I was searching futilely through the `forecast` documentation, and couldn't figure out the answer, and once I saw this one, I was able to figure out how to do it in the `forecast` package.  SO is great...